# [NodeJs Upgrading from ADAL to MSAL]: Cannot create property 'authenticationScheme' on string

Tags: node.js, azure-ad-msal, adal, msal.js, adal.js

We are Upgrading from ADAL to MSAL when doing so we are facing issues.
[image]

The Code we implemented is

```
 const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
  const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: config.clientId,
            authority: config.authorityUrl,
            clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
            knownAuthorities: [],
        },
    }
 let cca = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
   const tokenResponse = async function() {
        console.log("callled tokenr response");

        try {
          const response =  cca.acquireTokenByUsernamePassword(config.scopeBase,config.pbiUsername,config.pbiPassword);
          
          return Promise.resolve(response);
        } catch(error) {
  
         return Promise.reject(error);
        }
```

Can anyone help me how can i fix this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acquireTokenByUsernamePassword accepts a single parameter which should be an object with the shape defined [here](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_node.html#usernamepasswordrequest). You are passing in 3 parameters of type string.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, My problem is resolved and also I passed incorrect scope that's also one of the problem.